# Adding js variable value to an input field

Tags: javascript, populate

How can I get the value from a javascript variable which is in its own .js file and populate a hidden field with it? I've never attempted anything like this so I really have no idea of what even to google for.

Answer (score 3):

```
var f = document.getElementById("myHiddenFieldId");
if (f) {
  f.value = myVar;
}
```

Be sure to use this script on page load or in script block somewhere beneath your hidden field. Also be sure that you external js file is loaded, so onload handler would be safest place.

UPDATE: Using jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#myHiddenFieldId").val(myVar);
});
```

UPDATE: in your specific case you could try with

```
var value = dragtable.readCookie("dragtable-" + "myTableId");
if (value) {
  jQuery("#myHiddenFieldId").val(value);
}
```

Comment: question if my variable is defined inside a function in the javascript file how can I get it? Because I added your script and it said "Uncaught ReferenceError: new_val is not defined"

Comment: Your js file has not been loaded yet. Do you use plain javascript or some js framework like jQuery?

Comment: both, but mostly jQuery and the variable I want to get I have it inside a plugin I'm using called "dragtable.js"

Comment: I've updated answer with jQuery on ready. Which variable (name) are you trying to access?

Comment: it's called "new_val" it's in line 389

Comment: Are we talking about http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dragtable. Which version? I searched through files and cannot find "new_val"

Comment: I've found your plugin. new_var is rememberDrag function's private variable so it cannot be done.

Comment: is there a way to get the value into a public variable and so get it into the hidden field?

Comment: Yes you could modify plugin, but first try with code I;ve updated answer with.